# Amazon Redshift Block Size 1 MB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Amazon redshift is a columnar MPP database and it stores the data in 1 MB block.Can anyone help me to understand why Redshift chooses the data block size as 1 MB ?

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you want it bigger or smaller? How is it impacting your requirements?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's not impacting anything but just to understand why its like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing the physical disk I/O system for databases, common block sizes are 4 KB, 64 KB and 1 MB. The larger the block size the faster the sequential I/O performance. There is a trade off between speed and wasted space.